# Query improvement - gremlin

Tags: javascript, jquery, nosql, gremlin, janusgraph

Problem : Here I am trying to retrieve all the post count by its type

Explaining further more,

- There are 8 vertices ( post_article,post_gallery,post_chirpy...)
- Each having a property ( 'type','{{vertex_label}}') - for indexing

  Response :{  “data”: { “total_articles”: 500, “total_chirpies”: 250, “total_events”: 600, “total_shouts”: 400, “total_forums”: 750, “total_galleries”: 700, “total_polls”: 900, “total_groups”: 260  },  “meta”: { “status”: 0, “message”: “success”  } }

So here I have wrote the below query to get this output

```
let data = await g
    .V()
    .has("type", 'post_article')
    .count()
    .store("1")
    .V()
    .has("type", 'post_chirpy')
    .count()
    .store("2")
    .V()
    .has("type", 'post_gallery')
    .count()
    .store("3")
    .V()
    .has("type", 'post_shout')
    .count()
    .store("4")
    .V()
    .has("type",'post_forum')
    .count()
    .store("5")
    .V()
    .has("type", 'post_gallery')
    .count()
    .store("6")
    .V()
    .has("type", 'post_poll')
    .count()
    .store("7")
    .V()
    .has("type", 'groups')
    .count()
    .store("8")
    .project(
      "total_articles", //1
      "total_chirpies", //2
      "total_events", //3
      "total_shouts", //4
      "total_forums", //5
      "total_galleries", //6
      "total_polls", //7
      "total_groups" //8
    )
    .by(__.cap("1"))
    .by(__.cap("2"))
    .by(__.cap("3"))
    .by(__.cap("4"))
    .by(__.cap("5"))
    .by(__.cap("6"))
    .by(__.cap("7"))
    .by(__.cap("8"))
    .next();
```

Is there any way to improve the above query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a good time to use `groupCount()` to me:

```
g.V().has("type",within('post_article','post_chirpy',
                        'post_gallery','post_shout',
                        'post_forum','post_gallery',
                        'post_poll','groups')).
  groupCount().by('type')
```

Comment: Thanks. Wanted to share one concern here, while comparing both queries, found the first one had better performance than the second. Is it due to the 'within' ?

Comment: interesting - not sure what might happen there. maybe the `count()` in janusgraph optimizes better than an in-memory count with `groupCount()`. how much faster was your query? i see you use janusgraph based on the question tag, perhaps you should check-in with their community to see if anyone has any insights on that.

Comment: What kind of index did you create for the `type` property? If it's a mixed index, then JanusGraph can let the index backend do the count which should be more efficient than retrieving all elements and then counting them in-memory. A `profile()` output for both queries could also be helpful to explain the performance difference.

Comment: @stephenmallette Yes I use janusgraph and the query round-time was 300ms faster than second one.

Comment: @FlorianHockmann Yep that's right I used mixed indexing ( es ). So as requested here are the performance details for the second query     \_query=byTypeMixed:[((type = post_article OR type = post_chirpy OR type = post_gallery OR type = post_sh
            out OR type = post_forum OR type = post_poll OR type = groups))](2000):byTypeMixed
    \_limit=2000
GroupCountStep(value(type))                                            1           1          82.246     4.70
                                            >TOTAL                     -           -        1748.577        -